# Hide or add new line to variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables

Let's say I have this variable in my C# Code

```
string longVariableStuff = "hsduifgnw8e7rty83rfgediguidogy7834rghf7834ghf170934hf7034hgf734gf8170g437fg73408g1f784g1387fg4731gf7g13fg18347gf78134gf7834gf780134gfuhsdjkfhsdjkafhldsj";
```

Every time I'm coding, it gets a bit annoying when I scroll back it with the keyboard and my screen jumps to the right.

Is there anyway to just minimize it? Or maybe add a new line in the middle so I can view the whole thing without scrolling right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can just break it up:

```
string longVariableStuff = 
    "hsduifgnw8e7rty83rfgediguidogy7834rghf7834ghf170934hf7034hgf7" + 
    "34gf8170g437fg73408g1f784g1387fg4731gf7g13fg18347gf78134gf783" + 
    "4gf780134gfuhsdjkfhsdjkafhldsj";
```

This incurs absolutely no performance penalty, because the strings will be concatenated back into one string at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have really long strings it could be easier to manage them as string resource.

Right click on the project > Properties > Resources. Select `Strings` from the combo box. Enter a resource name and the string.

[image: string resource in VS]

After saving, you should be able to access your string with

```
string s = Properties.Resources.MyStringName;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Blorgbeard probably has the better answer, but there is a second way

```
string x = @"abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd";
```

Will get you "abcdabcdabcdabcd".  The other version is much cleaner though so you should probably use that, I'm just adding this as an alternative.

**Second idea that technically solves your problem but is a little clunky:**
You can use a region to hide it in visual studio so you don't have to look at it when you don't have to.

```
#region my long string is in here
string longVariableStuff = "hsduifgnw8e7rty83rfgediguidogy7834rghf7834ghf170934hf7034hgf734gf8170g437fg73408g1f784g1387fg4731gf7g13fg18347gf78134gf7834gf780134gfuhsdjkfhsdjkafhldsj";
#endregion
```

Visual studio will allow you to collapse it so you don't have to look at it, and it won't affect horizontal scrollbar as you move the cursor over it.

Comment: Note that the line breaks are included in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using the c# verbatim operator 
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

```
string multilinestring = @"my-
multiline
string";
```

Comment: Won't that add white space?

Comment: It does add the whitespace, that is why I left justified it when I gave basically the same answer right before.

Answer (score -1):

StringBuilder is the performant way to concatenate long strings together.

String interpolation is another performant way. $"{a}{b}"

Comment: Incorrect. StringBuilder is the performant way to concatenate *many* strings together (e.g. in a loop), *at runtime*. Plain old string concatenation is the performant way to concatenate string *literals* together at *compile-time*.